# Need to know the standard/general resolution for Android designs?

Tags: android-layout, dimensions, dpi

I need to know the standard/general resolution for all android designs, Currently i choose 72 dpi but on android developer blog, they have something that confusing me

```
(Baseline) mdpi: 1.0 { 320x480 (~160dpi) } 100%.
xhdpi: 2.0  { 640x960 (~320dpi)} 200% of Baseline.
hdpi: 1.5 { 480x800 (~240dpi)}    150% of Baseline
ldpi: 0.75  {240x320 (~120dpi)}. 75% of Baseline.
```

I am not getting it, Can anyone help me out on this? I want to follow standard pattern but its really complicated now.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means the resolution ratio between ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi is 3:4:6:8. In other words, if for example you have a 30x30px image you want to use for ldpi, you need to have it as 40x40 for mdpi, 60x60 for hdpi and 80x80 for xhdpi.